# Checkbox not being checked when running function

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox that when it is clicked it submits the form to the server to store the detail. All works fine except that after the form is submitted I update a div to say submitted but the checkbox isn't ticked. The page isn't refreshed of course and upon page refresh it is ticked.

I thought I might be able to check the box myself as I'm using jQuery but I have a lot of these checkboxes each with a dynamic name so I'm not sure how I would call them. I thought something like:

```
$('input[name=("favourite" + id)]').attr('checked', true);
```

might work but no luck. If I don't call the function on the checkbox being ticked the checkbox behaves normally.

Thanks for anything that could help.

Comment: You didn't supply all of the specifics, so I'll bet on Door Number 2 and guess you have a typo in the id/name of the field. Maybe something as simple as a '-' instead of a '_'. Happens to me all the time.

Comment: Just checked and I retrieve the value of the checkbox using something similar document.getElementsByName("favourite" + id) so I don't think thats it. I can post more code if you want but I don't think it will do anything other than confuse people. Just think I can solve it by fixing up the published line somehow. I am doing this just below $('#msg' + id).html("Submitted") and that works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should break your string in order to introduce the value of the `id` variable into your selector, you can do it like this:

```
$('input[name="favourite' + id + '"]').attr('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
$('input[name=("favourite" + id)]').checked = true;
```

instead.

The issue may be that setting the attribute is not automatically interpreted by your browser as changing the DOM property. This is a bit confusing, but on browsers like Firefox, etc, HTML attributes and DOM properties are stored separately (most are named the same, but there are exceptions - such as the `class` attribute being represented by the `className` property).

Changing properties affects the behavior of the Elements, while attributes do not always have the same effect - on some browsers they are only parsed during initial render.

Comment: Also $('input[name=("favourite" + id)]').attr('checked','checked'); might give you better results as the checked attribute is supposed to be a string. However i've the above method works more consistantly.